# ¿Cómo consultar un array dentro de un array con AngularJS (Angular 1)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un arreglo que deseo consultar mediante *Angular* con la directiva `ng-repeat` pero no encuentro la manera de acceder a los elementos dentro del arreglo interno.

Por ejemplo:

```
$scope.preguntas=[{
    pregunta:"Pregunta?",
    respuestas:["Respuesta1","Respuesta2"]
}];
```

Esto lo quiero consultar de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="preg in preguntas">
    Pregunta:{{ preg.pregunta}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Eso tengo para la pregunta pero no encuentro cómo acceder a las respuestas, ya intenté algo como `preg.respuestas`, `preg in preguntas.respuestas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta ya la tienes. ¿Cómo iteras un arreglo con directivas AngularJS? Pues con `ng-repeat`. Solo tienes que iterar `preg.respuestas` y mostrarlas en el HTML.

```js
angular
  .module('myapp', [])
  .controller('questionController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.preguntas=[{
        pregunta:"¿Qué etiquetas son más populares en SOes?",
        respuestas:["Java", "PHP", "JavaScript", "Android"]
    }];
  }]);
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'ubuntu', 'segoe ui';
}

h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li > ul > h4 {
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="myapp">
  <h3>Preguntas</h3>
  <ul ng-controller="questionController as AC">
    <li ng-repeat="preg in preguntas">
      {{ preg.pregunta}}
      <ul>
        <h4>Respuestas</h4>
        <li ng-repeat="resp in preg.respuestas">
          {{ resp }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: gracias, otra duda como podría agregar elementos al arreglo interno es decir a respuestas:["Java", "PHP", "JavaScript", "Android"] intente con preguntas.respuestas.push("CSS"); pero no funciona supongo que no se hace asi, gracias de antemano

Comment: Debes hacerlo en el controlador. Por ejemplo, definir una función en el controlador `$scope.addResponse(pregunta, respuesta) { ... }` que primero obtenga la pregunta (primer parámetro) para obtener sus respuestas y añadir la nueva (segundo parámetro).

Comment: hola si tengo lago asi pero eso me genera solo una pregunta con una respuesta y necesito algo como $scope.addResponse(pregunta, respuesta1, repsuesta2) pero dependo de que nunca se cuantas respuesta pueden dar y no puedo recibir 2 como parámetro y si ocupo 3? me imagino que tendría que mandar un arreglo o algo así atraves de angular pero no se bien como

Comment: No es necesario enviar un arreglo. Puedes usar rest parameters: `$scope.addResponse(pregunta, ...respuestas)` donde `respuestas` es un número indefinido de valores. También puedes usar `arguments`: `$scope.addResponse(pregunta) { var respuestas = arguments.slice(1); ...  }`.

Answer (score 2):

Debería funcionar accediendo al `respuestas` desde `preg` , puede que tengas el error de intentar añadir un `li` dentro de otro `li` , puede ser un motivo para que no te muestre los datos.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controlador", function($scope) {
$scope.preguntas=[
  {
      pregunta:"Pregunta?",
      respuestas:["Respuesta1","Respuesta2"]
  }

];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="preg in preguntas">
   Pregunta : {{ preg .pregunta}}
 <div ng-repeat="child in preg.respuestas">
  {{$index+1}}- {{child}} 
 </div>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```